# How to Mock a Custom $http Transform with Sinon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, sinon

Trying to understand the right way to mock an http post with a custom transform in Angular using the Sinon mocking framework.

I setup mocks in a CoffeeScript Sinon unit test like this:

```
beforeEach module(($provide) ->
mockHttp = {}
$provide.value('$http', mockHttp))
```

And I assert that this is being called with

```
expect(mockHttp.post).to.have.been.calledWith('/api/v1/something/' + id)
```

According to Sinon's documentation, mocking a method call for a standard get or post transform looks like this:

```
mockHttp.post.returns(q.when({}))
```

This should mean "when you call the post, then return a promise with an empty object".

That mock setup works for JavaScript code under test that looks like this:

```
service.create = function(arg) {
  return $http.post('/api/v1/something/' + arg {token: token }).then(
    function(response) {
      return response.data;
    }
  );
};
```

But how do you handle the case where there is no method being called on the line where you say "$http.post", and instead you have:

```
service.customPostback = function(arg1) {
return service.doSomething(arg1).then(
  function(response) {
    return $http.post(
      'http://mypostback.url',
          {
        "name":"value"
      }
        ).then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      }
    );
  };
```

For information about this in Angular, see [Overriding the Default Transformations Per Request](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request)

The mock setup I have is not enough to cover the callback inside of doSomething(arg1).
When I run my test I get that mockHttp.post is not being invoked.

What does the right mock setup look like for this JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was this mock setup:

```
mockHttp.post.withArgs('/api/v1/something/' + someId + '/dosomething').returns(q.when({ data: somedata }))
```

And then this custom expect with a Sinon match:

```
expect(mockHttp.post).to.have.been.calledWith(
  doSomething.url,
  {
    param1: 'value1',
    param2: 'value2'
  },
  sinon.match({ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }))
```

Comment: If anyone has a more general example of how this works, I'd be happy to accept that answer instead.
The answer I have here works, but it's hard to understand why that is just by reading it.